# Set up STM32f1xx MCU for SPI communication in slave mode

Tags: stm32, spi, arm

I set up an stm32f1xx MCU SPI for slave mode.

How can I write in the SPI shift register that whenever the controller starts a full-duplex communication, the data written to the SPI shift register is transferred to the controller?

[image]

Comment: Have you read the MCU reference manual how the SPI works?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`SPI2->DR` is related to spi2 shift register, for example `SPI2->DR = 36;` write 36 in spi shift register and master can fetch this value Whenever it starts to communicate with slave

Comment: Hi, This answer isn't clear to me. Either (a) You are writing it as an *answer*, because it really does answer your original question (even though it doesn't seem to me that it answers the original question). In that case, please make it clear in this "answer" that you want to close the topic & come back in 48 hours to accept the answer. Or (b) You are mistakenly writing this as an *answer*, when in fact you still want replies / help. In that case, please think about where you should add this e.g. as an edit to update the question, or as a comment etc. Which applies here, (a) or (b)?

Comment: I 'm looking for a way to read or write in shift register of SPI communication and after some internet search, I understood writing or reading in  "SPI2->DR" is exactly  writing and reading in the SPI shift register.

Comment: Ali.kavari76 - Thanks for replying. I *think* you are saying that you have answered your own question, and you do not need any more replies. Therefore to close this whole question, please login again after 2021-03-22 17:33 UTC (i.e. minimum 48 hours after you asked the question) and then "accept" your own answer (click the "tick mark" to make it turn green). Thanks.